# Django filter by empty string or empty string made of spaces

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I would like to filter by a given name that is either an empty string or a string of only blank spaces

For example, I have these names

```
name1 = ''
name2 = '  '
name3 = '     '
name4 = 'john door'
```

I would like the query to return all values without characters but made of only spaces which in this case name 1, 2 and 3

Here is my initial attempt but I think it can be made more accurate.

```
missing_names = Loan.objects.filter(
    Q(Q(name__startswith=' ') & Q(name__endswith=' ')) | Q(name__exact='')
)
```

Comment: maybe a regex solution can help you:
`Loan.objects.exclude(name__regex=r'\w')` this return all the objects without characters, im not sure for the empty filter case.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`Trim` database function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#trim) to remove all the leading and trailing spaces and then filter on that:

```py
from django.db.models.functions import Trim


missing_names = Loan.objects.annotate(trimmed_name=Trim('name')).filter(trimmed_name='')
```

With Django 3.2+ you can use [`alias` <sup>[Django docs]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#alias) instead of `annotate`:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Trim


missing_names = Loan.objects.alias(trimmed_name=Trim('name')).filter(trimmed_name='')
```

Answer (score 2):

As for the problem you can use the [regex operator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex) the Django ORM provides

e.g.

```
missing_names = Loan.objects.filter(name__regex=r'/^\s*$/')
```